# Using open function and loops in Python

Tags: python

I want to use the loop function to give 5 strings: "Article 1", "Article 2" and so on... After this I would like to fetch the information below the articles that come in a text file. For example:

```
Article 1. It is not good to eat pizza after midnight
Article 2. I wouldn't survive a day withouth stackexchange
Article 3. All of these are just random phrases
Article 4. To prove if my experiment works.
Article 5. The red dog jumps over the lazy fox
```

The purpose of this is to separate each article in order to export it later as chunks of data in the same text format.
Here is what I have:

```
n=0
while n < 5:
  n = n + 1
  a = ('Article %(number)s' % {'number': n})
  print(a)
with open("LISR2.txt") as openfile:
  for line in openfile:
    if a in line:
       print(line)
```

But what I get is

```
C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe 
Article 1
Article 2
Article 3
Article 4
Article 5
Article 5. The red dog jumps over the lazy fox
```

Is this the right approach to what I am trying to do? Or do I just need to change a bit of my code syntax?

Comment: a doesn't appear to be in scope inside the with.

Comment: @Carcigenicate From the output, it appears that the `with` is using the final value of `a` after the `while` loop finishes execution.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer rather than editing your question. You should also accept an answer when the site allows you to. When you have more rep, you can also up vote answers which are helpful.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I must be forgetting python scoping. Is `a` actually available inside the `with`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm actually not familiar with the exact scoping rules. I am deducing behavior based on the OP's output. If `a` were not in scope, the output would include an error message.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I was assuming he neglected to mention that or tested with a different version of code. That's not uncommon.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, that is certainly a possibility. It appears that both you and I are too lazy to actually copy and paste the code given to verify the posted output.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Could have, given I have QPython on my phone. I'm literally going to bed though, so I didn't want to start something. That didn't really work out though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I understand the feeling. Close to bedtime for myself, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that code executes in exactly the order you type it. Also, indentation in Python determines nesting. This means that the `while` and `with` statements are at the same level and will be executed one after the other. If you want the `with` statement to execute for each "Article", then you must indent it another level so that it is inside the `while` loop rather than after it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I'm just getting started in Python and didn't even consider indentation, here's the solution:

```
n=0
while n < 5:
   n = n + 1
   a = ('Article %(number)s' % {'number': n})
   print(a)
   with open("LISR2.txt") as openfile:
     for line in openfile:
       if a in line:
          print(line)
```